# How do I get a multiplier to appear?

Tags: bejeweled-blitz

The way to get multipliers to appear is something I can't figure out. Do you just have to match a certain number of gems before one drops? Is it to do with the specific gem colours? I simply can't tell. Can you help me?

Comment: If my answer helped at all, please mark it as accepted for future possible viewers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/995171-bejeweled-blitz/answers/234582-how-are-multipliers-gained) FAQ, multipliers are obtained in accordance as to how many gems are destroyed. Also, according to their [Wiki](http://bejeweled.wikia.com/wiki/Multiplier_Gem):

> The first multiplier appears after 12 or more gems are destroyed in
>   one move. Additional multipliers are created after destroying 16 or
>   more gems in a single move. The chance of a multiplier appearing after
>   a big move gradually decreases as the multiplier increases.

I hope this helps.